# What is wrong with my Opencalais installation?

Tags: 7

I have installed and configured the [OpenCalais](https://www.drupal.org/project/opencalais) module (7.x-1.0-rc1) as specified in the readme text to tag feed items during feed import. But I am getting these error messages

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$body in
>   opencalais_get_suggestions() (line 378 of
>   /home/websitename/public_html/sites/all/modules/opencalais/opencalais.module).

and

> Unable to process, ARC2 Library is missing

I put the arc2 library in `/sites/all/libraries/arc/`

What is wrong with my installations? I tried different versions but I am getting the same error messages.